# adding more columns to a data table decreasing the size of the .RData object

Tags: r, data.table, rdata

I have a `data.table` with 30 million rows and 15 columns saved on the hard disk (size 177 MB, file 1).

I load this data in R, process it, and add 8 columns more (rows remain same) to it and save it again as an `.RData` file, but this time its size has decreased (144 MB, file 2).

How is this possible? Shouldn't the size increase of the `.RData` file if I have added more columns?

**EDIT: Initial file is data.table (in R) which I store it as .RData on hard disk (file 1, 177 MB). I then load it back in R, process it, add more columns (rows remain same) and save it back (file 2, 144 MB).**

Comment: .RData is the Compressed file that takes less storage space. Hence more useful to store R objects.

Comment: What's the format of the original data? Is it a text file (e.g., CSV) or an `.RData` file? Also, can you post a reproducible example (e.g., simulate data, write it, read it back it in, and then save it again)?

Answer (score 1):

The [`.Rdata` help file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/save.html) expands upon MAPK's comment and notes that:

> Large files can be reduced considerably in size by compression. A particular 46MB R object was saved as 35MB without compression in 2 seconds, 22MB with gzip compression in 8 secs, 19MB with bzip2 compression in 13 secs and 9.4MB with xz compression in 40 secs. The load times were 1.3, 2.8, 5.5 and 5.7 seconds respectively. These results are indicative, but the relative performances do depend on the actual file: xz compressed unusually well here.
>
> It is possible to compress later (with gzip, bzip2 or xz) a file saved with compress = FALSE: the effect is the same as saving with compression. Also, a saved file can be uncompressed and re-compressed under a different compression scheme (and see resaveRdaFiles for a way to do so from within R).

Comment: I'm confused - how does this answer the OP? I.e. how does this explain that OP gets a smaller size with more columns?

Comment: I'm pretty sure both the text of the OP and the title make it clear that both the start and the end points are an .RData file